# Java Mongodb numberlong query

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to get specific data from mongoDB. I have 5 fields that user can make search based on these. Here is my code :

```
Map<Object, Object> fields = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
if (textField.getText().length() != 0)
    fields.put("FirstName", textField.getText());
if (textField_1.getText().length() != 0)
    fields.put("LastName", textField_1.getText());
if (textField_2.getText().length() != 0)
    fields.put("City", textField_2.getText());
if (textField_3.getText().length() != 0)
    fields.put("EmailAddress", textField_3.getText());
if (textField_4.getText().length() != 0)
    fields.put("PhoneNumber", "NumberLong(" + textField_4.getText() + ")");
query.putAll(fields);
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
DBCursor result = coll.find(query);
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> list = createListDataMongo(result);
```

All of the search fields works except for phone number. When I have added to the query phone number nothing returns. `PhoneNumber` is a `NumberLong` field in my mongoDB database. How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fields.put("PhoneNumber", "NumberLong(" + textField_4.getText() + ")");
```

searches for documents where `PhoneNumber` has the value `"NumberLong(" + textField_4.getText() + ")"` of type `text`(String).

Please try this.

```
fields.put("PhoneNumber", Long.parseLong(textField_4.getText()));
```

And as usual, handle the exceptions.